# AttributError: 'module' has no attribute

Tags: python

So I am trying to make it so that the following code tells me what the random result is:

```
import random

pizza_toppings = ["bacon", "cheese", "chicken", "pepperoni", "olives"]
pizza_sauce = ["alfredo", "marinara", "ranch", "BBQ"]

def pizza(number_of_toppings):
  final_sauce = random.pizza_sauce
  final_toppings = []
  for i in range(number_of_toppings):
    final_topping = random.pizza_toppings
    append.final_topping(final_toppings)
  final_result = print("Your pizza with ", final_topping, " with ", final_sauce, " is ready I guess...")
  return final_result
pizza(2)
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'pizza_sauce'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access an attribute from a module (which does not exist). You should have done

```
final_sauce = random.choice(pizza_sauce)
```

instead (if you're trying to select a random element from given list).